# How can I remove pages that I don't want to appear on the bottom bar in expo router

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I am using expo's own router structure. in the layout it automatically adds pages to the bottom bar, I want to remove some pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the views by passing the prop `href: null`. see the docs https://expo.github.io/router/docs/guides/tabs#hiding-a-tab

```
export default function AppLayout() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen
        // Name of the route to hide.
        name="index"
        options={{
          // This tab will no longer show up in the tab bar.
          href: null,
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

Comment: I hope this doesn't break deep linking